# Must I register all components in ngModule?

Tags: angular

I have a component which uses a number of nested components in its template. These components are specifically designed to work as children for the parent component. It's a typical abstraction for a table.

I'd like to be able to use the parent component without having to know what sort of nested components it relies on. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to achieve this, so I have to register all components in the `@NgModule.declarations` array.

Is it possible to only register the parent component, which in turn loads the nested components as dependencies?

Comment: Well, I guess you can create a module in the same component file and declare its dependencies.  Take a look at the components in the primeng repository https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/tree/master/components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yes.

you can create a parent module which declares its direct child components or import child modules and this parent module can be imported in main module.

For ex:

```
NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AccountModule, // <---- module for account
    MainModule,  // <---- module for main
    DirectivesModule,
  ],
  providers,
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule , 
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent, 
    SettingsComponent
  ]
})
export class AccountModule { }; // Account module


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule , 
    DirectivesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent,
    PageOneComponent,
  ]
})
export class MaintModule { }; // Main module
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**No**

There are many ways you can dismay your components without adding them in the container module. one of the them is lazy load module and its component

you can zaly load components of another module by

```
  {
    path: 'routerpath',
    loadChildren: 'modulecode#NamedModule'
  }
```